# Matlab to Mathematica code to solve system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, code-request, code-review, matlab

I have the following system of second order non-homogeneous DEs:

\begin{align}
0 &= 2 x_t - J_{\pi_t}(x_t) \frac{\epsilon - 1}{\theta} (1 + \varphi) + \frac{\partial J_{x_t}(x_t)}{\partial x_t} \left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 J_{x_t}(x_t)}{\partial x_t^2} \sigma^x - \delta J_{x_t}(x_t) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
0 &= 2 \lambda (a_0 + a_1 x_t) - J_{x_t}(x_t) + \frac{\partial J_{\pi_t}(x_t)}{\partial x_t} \left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 J_{\pi_t}(x_t)}{\partial x_t^2} \sigma^x
\end{align}

Subject to the following boundary conditions:

\begin{align}
J_{x_t}(\hat{x}) &= 0 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
J_{x_t x_t}(\hat{x}) &= 0 \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
J_{\pi_t}(\hat{x}) &= \frac{2 \theta}{(\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)} \hat{x} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
J_{\pi_t x_t}(\hat{x}) &= \frac{2 \theta}{(\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)} 
\end{align}
where $J_{x_t x_t}$ and $J_{\pi_t x_t}$ denote the derivative of my two dependent variables $J_{x_t}$ and $J_{\pi_t}$ with respect to the independent variable $x_t$. Notice that the formatting is not great but the boundary conditions holds at $x_t=$xhat.

I have attempted to solve and plot the system as follows:

**Mathematica**

```
delta = 1/100;
theta = 2;
epsilon = 3/2;
curlyphi = 3/2;
xi = 5/1000;
lambda = 1/2;
sigma = (1/5)^2;
muA = 3/20;
sigmaA = 1/5;
rn = delta + muA - sigmaA^2;
em = (delta*theta - Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
ep = (delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a1 = (-delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a0 = -((xi + rn - 1/2*sigma - sigmaA*Sqrt[sigma])/(delta + a1))*a1;
xhat = -0.08;

OdeM = 1/2*sigma*J1''[x] + ((a0*delta)/a1 - a1*x)* J1'[x] - (epsilon - 1)/theta*(1 + curlyphi)* J2[x] - delta*J1[x] == -2*x;
OdeP = 1/2*sigma*J2''[x] + ((a0*delta)/a1 - a1*x)*J2'[x] - J1[x] == -2*lambda*(a0 + a1*x);
Ic1 = J1[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = J1'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = J2[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi))* xhat;
Ic4 = J2'[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi));
sol = NDSolve[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {J1[x], J2[x]}, {x, -0.3, xhat}]
Plot[{J1[x], J2[x]} /. sol, {x, -0.3, xhat}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "J1 and J2"}]
```

*Output:*

[image]

I am suspicious about this solution because I know that the problem that generated this system of DEs requires that $J_{x_t}$ be positive throughout. After attempting for several hours different approaches, I have asked ChatGPT to write the code to solve the same problem in Matlab. I am by no means an expert in Matlab so it may be that there are some mistakes. I have however done my very best to ensure that the code makes sense and is error free.

**Matlab**

```
% Parameters
delta = 1/100;
theta = 2;
epsilon = 3/2;
curly_phi = 3/2;
xi = 5/1000;
lambda = 1/2;
sigma = (1/5)^2;
mu_A = 3/20;
sigma_A = 1/5;
rn = delta + mu_A - sigma_A^2;
em = (delta*theta - sqrt(delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curly_phi)))/(2*theta);
ep = (delta*theta + sqrt(delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curly_phi)))/(2*theta);
a1 = (-delta*theta + sqrt(delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curly_phi)))/(2*theta);
a0 = -((xi + rn - 1/2*sigma - sigma_A*sqrt(sigma))/(delta + a1))*a1;
xhat = -0.08;

% Differential equations and boundary conditions
odeM = @(x, J) [J(2); -2*sigma*((a0*delta)/a1 - a1*x)*J(2) + 2*(epsilon - 1)/theta*(1 + curly_phi)*J(4) + 2*delta*J(1) + 4*x; J(4); -2*sigma*((a0*delta)/a1 - a1*x)*J(4) + 2*J(1) + 4*lambda*(a0 + a1*x)];

bc = @(J0, Jxhat) [Jxhat(1); Jxhat(2); Jxhat(3) - (2*theta)/((epsilon-1)*(1+curly_phi))*xhat; Jxhat(4) - (2*theta)/((epsilon-1)*(1+curly_phi))];

% Solve the system of differential equations
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(-0.3, xhat, 100), [0 0 0 0]);
sol = bvp5c(odeM, bc, solinit);

% Plot the solutions
x = linspace(-0.3, xhat, 100);
J1 = deval(sol, x, 1);
J2 = deval(sol, x, 3);

figure
plot(x, J1, 'LineWidth', 2)
hold on
plot(x, J2, 'LineWidth', 2)
hold off
xlabel('x')
ylabel('J1 and J2')
title('Solutions of the System of Differential Equations')
legend('J1', 'J2')
grid on
```

*Output:*

[image]

This solution satisfies the positivity constraint that I know needs to holds.

**Question:**

Can you please help me understand why I don't obtain the same solution in both cases?

Comment: In OdeM and OdeP you should write: `sigma^x` instead of only "sigma". But the first function is still negative.

Comment: I changed it to sigma because in my previous posts related to this question it was highlighted how Mathematica's Solver had some problems with the name of that variable, so I simplified it as much as possible as suggested by other users.

Comment: `AsymptoticDSolveValue` agrees with `NDSolve`: `xhat = -8/100;
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {J1[x], 
   J2[x]}, {x, xhat, 4}] // N` --> `{-4.65271 (0.08 + x)^4, ...}`

Comment: So that's the Mathematica solution. It's not that I am making any mistakes. Can it be that the starting values it uses are the problem?

Comment: It's not ***the*** Mathematica solution. It's *two* Mathematica solutions, one numerical and one symbolic. The consistency of a numerical and an analytical method is strong evidence of their being correct. So if J1 is indeed supposed to be positive, there's a problem in the setup, that is, in the ODEs, in the ICs, or in the parameter settings.

Comment: Code for Matlab is not the same as for Mathematica. If your Matlab code is right, then please, check your equations shown in Latex and Mathematica code.